# IOS: UIgesture for drag an drop

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

In my app I should implement the drag and drop of a imageView; the problem is that my imageView is inside a scrollview; it's my code

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *downwardGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragGestureChanged:)];
[scrollViewAlfabeto addGestureRecognizer:downwardGesture];
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in myscrollView.gestureRecognizers)
{
    [gestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:downwardGesture];
}
}

- (void) dragGestureChanged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:scrollViewAlfabeto];

if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
{

    [imageViewToMove removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:imageViewToMove];

    UIView *draggedView = [myscrollView hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
    if ([draggedView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        imageViewToMove = (UIImageView*)draggedView;
    }
}
else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    imageToMove.center = point;
}
else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded     ||
         gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
         gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
{
    // Determine if dragged view is in an OK drop zone
    // If so, then do the drop action, if not, return it to original location

    NSLog(@"point.x final:%f", point.x);
    NSLog(@"point.y final:%f", point.y);

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(goal.frame, point)){
        imageToMove.frame = CGRectMake(167, 159, 100, 100);
    }

    else{

    [imageToMove removeFromSuperview];
    [myscrollView addSubview:imageToMove];
    [imageToMove setFrame:CGRectMake(12, 38, 100, 100)];
    imageToMove = nil;



    }
}
}
```

Then with my code I'm able to take an imageView from scrollView with longpress, drag it inside "self.view"; also if I drop this imageView over another imageView in self.view it puts on it. It work fine. But I have two problems:

1- when I drag this imageView and I do

```
[imageViewToMove removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:imageViewToMove];
```

the image view don't appear under my finger but in other position and I want that it remains under my finger

2- This code work only the first time when I launch my viewcontroller, because If I don't drop the imageview over other imageview inside self.view, itr return inside scrollview, but If I want drag it a second time, it don't work.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not advanced in objc, but...

1. Allow user ineraction `[self.view userInteractionEnabled:YES];`
2. Try `[self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];`

Taken from the documentation of UIView in relation to *userInteractionEnabled*:

> **Discussion** 
>   When set to NO, user events—such as touch and
>   keyboard—intended for the view are ignored and removed from the event
>   queue. When set to YES, events are delivered to the view normally. The
>   default value of this property is YES.
>
> During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for
>   all views involved in the animation, regardless of the value in this
>   property. You can disable this behavior by specifying the
>   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option when configuring the
>   animation.

Hope it works